# Vietnamese text printing on ZPL printer using Zpl commands

Tags: label, odoo, zebra-printers, zpl

I am trying to print Vietnamese text on my Zebra label using Zpl coding.
But i am getting issues in vietnamese characters. For example, i am trying to print a label with text "Nhập khẩu" but it is giving me the output "Nh p kh u", thus missing the Vietnamese fonts.
I have tried using Andale and Swiss font and also declaring the ^CI28 tag for printing various characters in utf-8 encoding.
If anyone else has any other inputs, please let me know.. thanks in advance..

EDIT:
This is the code i am using..
^XA^CWZ,E:TT0003M_.TTF^FS^XZ
^XA
^CF01,20,15
^CI28
^FO20,20^FDNhập khẩu - LOẠI:For Fujifilm^FS
^XZ

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried google's Noto fonts?

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Noto+Sans

I have used them to render Vietnamese. If that doesn't work, post the sample ZPL you have tried and we can work through it.

Here is some example ZPL.  This assumes the Noto Sans font is saved to the printer as `E:NOTOSANS.TTF`:

```
^XA^CI28
^A@N,32,32,E:NOTOSANS.TTF
^FO50,50
^FDNhập khẩu^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for answering my question.. no i haven't tried the google's Noto fonts..I'll try them now,.. also i have added the code to the question.. that i am using currently..

Comment: Also can you please provide me a sample of how i should use code for the Noto fonts.. i'll install the fonts to my printer..

Comment: Added some example ZPL using the Noto Sans font.  Hope that helps.